# Filling holes in a mesh

Tags: modeling, mesh

I'm currently designing a space window, shown in this picture
[image]

Currently I got this far:
[image]

So I have  problem with filling the smaller Windows,
I want to fill them em with these windows just like in the picture, but I cant really do it. How should I do this?

Comment: If you don't need continuous connecting topology, nor a single non intersecting object, just create a separate circle mesh object and let it intersect the frame inside

Comment: I didnt quite understand that.

Comment: Just create a new separate object shaped like a circle

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In most cases it's better to think ahead before you model something. More difficult to do with less experience. I would approach it this way *(I'm sure there is more than one way to model this).*

- Add a circle with 34 vertices
- In *Edit Mode*, extrude it four times by pressing <kbd>E</kbd> and <kbd>S</kbd> (Scale)
- Then extrude one more time but instead of scaling, 
  *Left Click* (<kbd>LMB</kbd>) and then press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> *> Collapse*.

[image]

Then select the following faces and Extrude up:

[image]

[image]

---

It's hard to tell from the reference image but if the window has a conical shape:

- Select the following interior *Vertices > Enable Proportional Editing > choose a Falloff type* 
  (I choose Linear)
- Grab them and select an axis to move them on (I used <kbd>G</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>)
- Control the number of vertices effected with the mouse wheel

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer Dontwalk! Is there any way i could make these limiters between the smaller windows an perfect linear objec just like in the picture?

Comment: @user5339049 - You can move the Edge Loops by pressing CTRL + "E" > Edge Slide. I would also delete half of the vertices and use the Mirror Modifier with "Clipping" selected.

Comment: you make it seem so easy :D  Do you know any good starter tutorial?

Comment: There are a lot of tutorials out there. This site has some quality ones https://www.blenderguru.com/ There is also YouTube. Happy Blendering!

Comment: These are very good, basic and short tutorials https://vimeo.com/nhirsig/videos

Answer (score 1):

I got another feeling about what your question: to me, it seems you wish to have a solid block of "glass" filling *exactly* those holes.

You can have them "easily" without reconstructing your mesh from scratch.

First, You need to "get the hole" from your current mesh.

In editmode, you need to select one of the interior "face rings"

[image]

you can do it manually, here I used a keyboard combination (<kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>ALT</kbd>) while right clicking on that face

[image]

then you need to duplicate this part of the mesh (ignore the tool that shows <kbd>CTRL</kbd> pressed, that was the screen capture...)

[image]

and then separate it (as another separate object) (again, ignore the tool that shows <kbd>CTRL</kbd> pressed, that was the screen capture...)

[image]

that's it: now the new object is selected, the wheel is no more.

[image]

now in edit mode, you need to add a bottom and top face to this face ring

[image]

starting from the bottom one, again, you can select the edge ring manually or use a key combination (<kbd>ALT</kbd>) while right clicking on that edge

[image]

now you simply create a face filling  that bottom edge ring

[image]

getting this

[image]

then you do the same for the top one

[image]

getting this

[image]

now getting back to object mode, and hiding the "window frame" you see the new object:

[image]

Note: it could be better to recalculate normals (in edit mode select all and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>).

Now you just need to assign a glass material to it. You can copy it for each other hole (maybe join all copies as a single object) and you should be done!

Note: a comment above telling you can do this as an "intersection" is quite right, but that needs a boolean modifier. In this case it could be faster, but it needs some experience, and you may prefer the steps above.

In any case here is what you need: "another "disc" (here painted blue) crafted to be used in the boolean difference (not intersection) to let the window frame to "cut" six windows from the blue disc.

Here is the disc

[image]

Now we put it "into" the window frame

[image]

next we add a boolean modifier to the blue disc, ad "difference" and as a target, the window frame object

[image]

That's it. Now, if you hide the window frame object, you see the object resulting from the boolean.

[image]

Applying the boolean modifier (use the "apply" button) will make this a real mesh, and not a boolean difference anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You could also add a window without remaking the whole mesh. This method isn't optimal, but it's simple, if you want to use it.

- Add a circle
- Scale it to the appropriate size
- Place it in the window holes.

You're done! :)

Notes:

- You can make the window a part of the same mesh by going into edit mode before adding the circle.
- If you want to add curve to the window, make a small circle (selecting triangle fan might be best), and extrude, then scale, to make a "loop cut" in the circle. Now you have geometry to curve.

Example:

[image]